# Cakephp :3 Get single data not working

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In controller I am trying to get username using `$this->auth->user('id')` Here I have found error get is a non object. I have tried below code.

```
$username = $Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'))->username;
echo $username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $this

```
$username = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'))->username;
```